# What is the right way to calculate 1080p 720p 360p 240p quality?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, resolution

I'm working on a video hosting project and I would like to know if I'm converting my videos quality the right way.

my equation is: newY=(y/x)*newX

so 1080p is:

```
    1080x460
   than 720p
    720x306
   ...
    480x204
    360x154
    240x102
    144x60
```

My problem is 360 and below comes out in a terrible quality. comparing that to youtube I'm wondering if they are actually changing the video resolution or just changing the kb/s?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question.  1080p is 1920x1080 (WxH), and 720p is 1280x720.  360p would be either 480x360 (for 4:3) or 640x360 (for 16:9).  What's your equation supposed to be calculating for you?

Comment: You're only dealing with the spatial resolution, not the quality which is affected by many factors like compression level.

Comment: You shouldn't expect good quality at lower resolutions.  I mean 360p on YouTube is horrible quality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1080 describes the vertical resolution of a video.  In your question you're using it as the horizontal resolution.   As techie mentioned in the comments, common video resolutions include:

- 1920 x 1080
- 1280 x 720
- 720 x 480
- 480 x 360
- 640 x 360

Comment: Yep, I should have checked myself better I was sure 1080p is the X...

Answer (score 5):

Use x264 (an [H.264](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) encoder) with constant quality.

In x264, this mode is called [Constant Rate Factor](http://slhck.info/crf.html). Lower values mean better quality. Use around 19–22 for very good quality. The default is 23.

Convert your video with Handbrake, VidCoder, Ripbot264, TEncoder, FFmpeg, etc.